# Parse Android - Wait the end of a ParseQuery ( when found something )

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse as a database.

I'm trying to code a function that search local info in order to put them on parse when a co appears !

But while I'm querying my `LocalDataStore` it's not waiting for fetching so it returns null ><

the function called when co is available is something like :

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PatientsAndroid");

    query.whereEqualTo("Mobile", Build.SERIAL); 
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {


                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject patient, com.parse.ParseException e) 
                {
                    if(e==null)
                    {
                      ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> trueLala = get_data_from_local()
                       put... [...] saveInBackground[...]
                    }
}});
```

My function get_data_from_local() which has to return the value from local :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> Lala = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>();
Lala = null;
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PatientsAndroid");

  query.fromLocalDatastore();
  query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() 
          {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject patient, com.parse.ParseException e) 
                {
                    Log.i("MOI", "On est dans la done ou PAS ?");

                    if(e==null) // There is the object !
                    {
                        try
                        {
                        Lala = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>) patient.get("Examens");

    // BASICALLY I WANT Lala to be return to first function up there !
                       patient.unpin();

                        } 
                        catch (ParseException e1) 
                        {
                            Log.i("MOI", "erreur destruction du localStorage + "+e1.toString());

                        }
                    }

                }
          });

    }
  catch(Exception e8)
 {
      Log.i("MOI", "erreur de query ! + "+e8.toString());
 }



    return Lala;  
}
```

But "trueLala" is null when testing :/ And it's because the function return the null value I put when I instantiate the Array for the return value ....

How can I do this ?